Sencha Extjs 7.7.0: pop-over is not displayed in grid component that contains combo box editor (cell editor)
In extjs version 7.7 pop-over is not displayed in grid component that contains combo box editor (cell editor)
While this problem does not exist in the previous version 7.6 .
Extjs Version 7.7 - With bug
Extjs Version 7.6 - Without bug
There is also this problem in the example of the Kitchen Sink (Classic).
Kitchen Sink 7.7 - With bug
Extjs Version 7.6 - Without bug

Thats not correct. Just the button to show the combobox is not working. You have to use the key-down. ;) I will report it to Sencha. Thanks for your finding.

This bug will be fixed in the next version, but Sencha does not have an ETA.
Until issue gets fixed in the official framework , please use the below override as a temporary workaround.
Ext.define('null', {
    override: "Ext.view.Table",
    focusPosition: Ext.emptyFn,
});

